# Transportation in more remote areas of Eastern Europe. Serbia, Bosnia, Croatia,

Tags: public-transport, taxis, rental, serbia, bosnia

This summer I will be traveling through a couple of East European countries from Romania to Serbia, Bosnia, Croatia and on and I would like to visit some of the natural sights that these countries have to offer. As I don't have a drivers license (could rent a moped though) I am entirely dependent on public transport.

While planning my trip, I find that some of the places I would like to visit (see below) are rather hard to get to. I've looked at websites like [rome2rio](https://www.rome2rio.com/) and [getbybus](https://getbybus.com/en/) that have proven very helpful but it appears that getting to some of these places, if only the last couple of miles, is only possible by car.

Could anyone tell me what means of transportation I have besides the aforementioned, whether it is easy to get a taxi in the more rural areas of the countries below or, otherwise give me some tips on how to explore these beautiful countries without being able to rent or drive a car? Thanks.

**Places we would like to visit that are or seem harder to reach**

1. Ceremosnja Cave, Serbia
2. Krupaj Springs, Serbia
3. Kravica, Bosnia
4. Vrelo Bune, Bosnia

Comment: There is not going to be a single answer to this. I googled Kravica and there is a lot of info.

Comment: I could make the question more specific if that would make more sense in your opinion. I find the first 3 places to be the hardest to get to. I wonder if perhaps there are alternative modes of transportation I was unable to find thus far.

Comment: You should ask five separate questions.

Comment: I will keep a close eye on the activity for a while but will definitely take your advise to heart. Thank you.

Comment: Here is info on [Una](https://getbybus.com/en/blog/bus-national-park-una/).

Comment: Thanks. It seems the english version of getbybus has some additional information! One down

Comment: Centrotrans seems to serve Kravica from Sarajevo (see http://www.centrotrans.com/domestic-lines).  The site is a little confusing, but I suspect that the Srebrenica bus, whose timetable is not available on the site, goes by way of Kravica.  I'm not sure why rome2rio doesn't show that, however, nor why the timetable is unavailable on the site.  It should be easy to find a taxi from Mostar to Vrelo Bune (note spelling).  It's a popular site.  There's also apparently a bus to Blagaj, which should put you within a couple of kilometers of the source.

Comment: Have you considered a bike?

Comment: Public transportation in Bosnia is really bad and unreliable. Information on the internet is often outdated, they change also too often their routes, go 1h later / earlier, because "things changed" (no more students, no more tourists, no more people from the German diaspora, etc., there's always a reason). I call always and ask for the correct time. What you should do is to hire some "guide" (= random taxist), you can hire someone (theoretically) for about 50 BAM per day (+ fuel, etc.), however as a tourist you'll have to pay about 100 BAM per day.

Comment: @Rg7xgW6acQ3g, bikes are rather hard to take with when depending on public transport. If renting one in the vicinity of places we want to visit is an option, sure. gladly even!

Comment: @ArminŠupuk, thank you. That comment is very helpful.

Comment: Ok, for everyone that took the time to answer this 'too broad' question, thank you. I will create two seprate questions for advise on getting around in Serbia and Bosnia. /peace

Comment: @CausaMortis yes, but bikes are the only alternative for single people without driving licence in regions with poor public transport. Larger groups can rent a bus/taxi but for single person it's a financial overkill...

Comment: @Rg7x gW6a cQ3g You can't generalize like that, Bosnia has very low loans. In industries like gastronomy / building / hotel / etc. the average loan is between 550-600 BAM (= about 300 EUR). Their purchasing power is one of the lowest in Europe (food costs about 150-200 BAM per month), so manpower is cheap and the difference to public transport isn't that big, depending on the route and region factor 3-6. However you don't need to hire someone the whole day, if you are doing some "normal" short trip. In Mostar you can get a taxi 2x 15km + 3h "waiting" for about 50 BAM (=25 EUR).

Comment: 2x 15km with Bus would be around 10 BAM (=5 EUR). In Switzerland you have to pay for 1h with the train in both directions 40 CHF (= 35 EUR), so for people from Western Europe 25 EUR shouldn't be overkill. It's really worth that money. The most routes between larger towns (!) are only served 2-5 times per day. The buses are "OK", but often grubby., not in time, etc.